# Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'setCapture'

Tags: google-maps

After making a change to some Google Maps code, I started getting the following error whenever I attempt to click-drag the map:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'setCapture'

Google turned up no results for this error, so I though I'd create this question.

Comment: Hmm. It actually seems that this error only occurs when Chrome's developer panel is open. Closing it causes the error to go away, and panning works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code??

Recently I'm having an error likely yours. I'm doing this, in my javascript code:

```
var components = $(".comp-div");

for ( var i = 0; i <= components .size(); i++) {
    components[i].css("width"));
}
```

When you use [] to access an item in a jQuery array, you get the DOM element not a jQuery object, probably you are doing this or something like, so it doesn't have any jQuery methods or any `google-maps` method.

I changed to use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function, see next example:

```
var components = $(".comp-div");

for ( var i = 0; i <= components .size(); i++) {
    components.eq(i).css("width"));
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Jacobi, this was a while ago and I couldn't have shared the code anyway. I'm familiar with the difference between a jQuery object and a DOM object, so I suspect that was not the problem in my case.